# Designing a database to host Kaggle like competitions

Tags: mysql, sql

we are building an application to host Kaggle like competitions. A competition has teams and a team has users in it. So we have created a `parent -> child -> grand-child` relationship in our database schema where:

- `competitions` is the parent table with PK `cid`
- `teams` is the child table having a FK to `competitions(cid)` and PK `tid`
- `users` is the grand-child table having FK to `teams(tid)` and  `uid` is id of the user

How do we now enforce following constraints:

1. a user can be part of only ONE team in a competition
2. but a user can participate in multiple competitions

If we add a unique constraint to `uid`, condition #1 is satisfied but now the user cannot participate in more than one competition.

And if we add a FK to `competitions(cid)` from the users table then it creates a problem in that the parent `teams` row also has a reference to `competitions` table and the two references can get out of sync (mismatch). Not to mention that it looks ugly - the `users` table is now both a grand-child of `competitions` as well as a child.

We are using MySQL 8.0.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it's not actually possible what you are saying. A user can be on multiple teams, so you need a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a team is simply any collection of users who collaborate on a competition, so essentially a team is defined by reference to both user and competition. So one option would be to store those three pieces of information in a single table, where a unique key is formed on both (user, competition), and (team,competition)